# Correlation: Test for linear dependence

Tags: correlation

**Setting the scene**: Assume a multivariate GBM with correlation matrix $\Sigma$. Further, one want to estimate the correlation between two of the assets. Assume one has a suitable estimator of the correlation, the exact estimator might not be directly relevant, so assume e.g. standard, 60 days moving average.

**Identifying the issue**: If one look at the time series of the correlations, it is obvious that a correlation is not constant over time, as postulated by gbm. Is there any good measure of "correlation volatility", i.e. a measure that says when a correlation seems stable? Alternatively, a measure that will quickly identify that the correlation is unrelieable?

**Attempt**: Ive tried to look at the maximum (absolute) changes of the close the last 60 days, and then created a band around todays estimation equal to $(p_t + max, p_t-max)$, where p is the correlation estimate and max is the max absolute movement. Then I have said that if this spread is higher than some given value (say 0.15), then the correlation is "unstable".

I have also tried different variation as looking at the maximum return, highest vs. lowest value etc. I am a bit vary to over-model this, so I hesistate to start giving correlation coefficient a probability distribution etc...

At the same time, I find my approach a bit unsatisfactory, and wondering if there is any "well designed" tests to see whether two variables satisfy such a linear dependence that correlation is...

Comment: I have started to be a bit vary of just looking at the correlation coefficients, as they are simply a number and could be stable although the returns do not follow a lognormal (or any other assumed distribution) walk with correlation p.

I guess one would have to look at the distribution as a whole, considering whether the observed data would be sampled from e.g. a bivariat normal distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying only to identify unstable correlations, or are you trying to incorporate time-varying correlation into your model?

If the latter, you may want to check out Engle's [Dynamic Conditional Correlation](http://weber.ucsd.edu/~mbacci/engle/391.PDF), which is an extent of GARCH modeling. In simplest terms, DCC models time-varying correlation parametrically via the GARCH residuals.

Another, slightly more exotic option is to consider a time-varying or conditional copula, such as those introduced by Andrew Patton. See for example his paper [Modelling Asymmetric Exchange Rate Dependence](http://public.econ.duke.edu/~ap172/Patton_IER_2006.pdf). Patton has also introduced goodness-of-fit measures for copulas.

Note that by inspecting the parameters of such models, you could evaluate the hypothesis that correlations are stable.

Comment: Thanks. I think the second paper maybe can solve some of my issues (restated in a comment above). I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have time seria you could postulate a linear equation for them:

x(t)=a*t+b giving a=x(t+1)-x(t)

There are lots of methods to deal with the hypothesis that a is zero or not, including low sample statistics to boost your confidence (levels) in the final result. In addition, by b-estimation you could see the "volatility" of your correlations.